# Calling existing variable (list) reconstructed with StringVar()

Tags: python, list, variables

I have a several lists that I am trying to activate or use that are named as follows:

```
public_forum_jr_soc = []
parliamentary_jr_soc = []
european_jr_soc = []
etc...
```

I have a bunch of radiobuttons that has variables to recreate these lists names, and it outputs something like this.

```
print(self.select_league.get()+self.select_age.get()+self.select_grade.get())

append_name = self.select_league.get()+self.select_age.get()+self.select_grade.get()
>>>
european_jr_soc
```

I try to proceed to use this list in as an argument for a function.

```
output_data(append_name)

def master_groper2(outof48):
    for i in outof48:
        if i[15] in ['ENGLISH','english','']:
            i[15] = 'English'
        elif i[15] in ['Mandarin','CHINESE',]:
            i[15] = 'Chinese'
```

However, I get a `IndexError: string index out of range` as python reads it as european_jr_soc, instead of the actual list, despite sharing the same name, how could I have python have it read it as the variable list?

Comment: It would make significantly more sense to reorganize your data first. Instead of having separate variables with different name fragments, have one nested dictionary or similar structure with keys. Something like `d = {"european": {"jr": {"soc": []}}}`. Then to do a lookup you just need `d[self.select_league.get()][self.select_age.get()][self.select_grade.get()]`.

Comment: Don't try to use variables like this,. Variables *shouldn't contain data*. You basically want to map strings to lists... then *use a map*, i.e. a `dict`.

Comment: "python reads it as european_jr_soc, instead of the actual list, despite sharing the same name" **of course it does**. `str` objects *are `str` objects*, they are **not variables**.